# printf command before closing the file descriptor still calling in the external file

Tags: c, system

I  wrote this code to get my hands working on the system calls. I expected the first printf to show result in the console.. but both of them are showing the the given file location..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

void main(){
printf("Hello World!!! Before close\n");
close(1);
int fd = open("/home/abhishek/Desktop/example.txt",O_RDWR);
printf("Hello World!!! After close");
}
```

Where actually am going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output to `stdout` may be buffered, and not actually written to the underlying file descriptor until the stream is flushed or closed. Try:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

before `close(1)`.

Note that mixing stdio and system file descriptor operations is not generally a good idea. Use one or the other, otherwise you may get confusing behaviour like you have shown.

Comment: Shouldn't the flushing had been be done by the call to `close()`?

Comment: @alk: No `close()` is not a stdio call, it is a system call and bypasses stdio completely.